# Check all parents in multiline checkboxtree with jquery

Tags: jquery, tree, parent

I have menu:

```
<ul>
    <li class="expanded">
        <span class="ui-icon">
        </span>
        <span class="ui-icon">
        </span>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="45">
            111111111
        </label>
        <ul id="ch-content-menu" class="ui-widget-content">
            <li class="expanded">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-se">
                </span>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="18">
                    22222222222222
                </label>
                <ul id="ch-content-menu" class="ui-widget-content">
                    <li class="leaf">
                        <span>
                        </span>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="19">
                            33333333333333
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="leaf">
                        <span>
                        </span>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="20">
                            4444444444
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I want to write a script that when I click on 4444444 checkbox, 2222222 and 1111111 checked automatically.

How I can do this with jquery?

Comment: You can do this with .each What have you tried?

Comment: Should this also apply if you click on 333333333333333333 ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify the id or name for the "44.." checkbox "22.." checkbox and the "11.." checkbox.

such as

```
<input id="44" type="checkbox"/>
<input id="22" type="checkbox"/>
<input id="11" type="checkbox" />
```

after that, you can use the script to monitor the action of those elements

```
$('#44').click(function(){
   $('#22').attr('checked',true);
   $('#11').attr('checked',true);
});
```

You can refer to the jquery website to see detail operations of checkbox.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I may miss understand the questioner. If you want to output 4000 boxes, I think you must have a program to generate it. Since you won't generate 4000 boxes by typing. The ID or name of each element must following a generation rules, in much of the time may use frequency numbers, such as box1, box2, box3...So you still use the script just like above.

If you want dynamic trigger which is following a triggering rule, say if one element have been clicked, check next two box at the same time. Then you can use

```
$('input').click(function(){
  var check_index = $(this).index();
  var next1 = check_index+1;
  var next2 = check_index+2;
  $('input#box'+next1+',input#box'+next2).click()});
```

or you can create the mapping object for selection

```
var mapping = {
  'box1':'#box4,#box5',
  'box44444':'#box222,#box111'
  ...
}
$('input').click(function(){
   $(mapping[this.id]).click();
});
```

of course you need to have a program to generate this map which generates by following a specify rule. But no matter in what method you use, you still need to give id or name for each element you want to act with if you want to have a stable performance of your script.

the best way is to use ID, if cannot, you may need to use get(), however, since get() retrieve jquery object to normal DOM object, you need to wrap it by $() again.

```
var ul3 = $('ul').get(3) // get the last ul
var target = $(ul3).find('input').get(1) // get the 4444 input
$(target).click(function(){
  var ul1 = $('ul').get(0) // get the first ul
  var inputs = $(ul1).find('input') // get all input element under the first ul
  $($(inputs).get(0)).click(); // get and click the first input element
  $($(inputs).get(1)).click(); // get and click the second input element
})
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: What if he has 4000 boxes?

Comment: @raam86 Sorry, I cannot see the questioner needs the script to process 4000 boxes in his question. But thanks you for your kindly reminding. I have updated my answer, hope it's helpful.

Comment: I have no ID. just with dom

Comment: @chalist I have updated my result. you can use the get() to select the element base on the index and find() to target a set of element.

Comment: @PandaYang thanks dude but not worked, I want a public method. not like this `$('ul').get(3)`

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to add id attribute to your input fields if they are few, but you can also try this jquery code :

```
$('label').click(function(){
    text = $.trim($(this).text())
    if (text == '4444444') {
        $('label').each(function(){
            text = $.trim($(this).text())
            if (text == '2222222' || text == '1111111') {
                $(this).children().attr('checked', true)
            }
        })
    }
})
```